# PHP load data in modal depending on the user picked item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can the data from a PHP Bootstrap modal dialogue be loaded?
In this case, products are dynamically loaded on the page. A User can click on any of the items, and depending on which item user clicked, Bootstrap modal should load the data of that clicked item.

PHP Code:

```
$products = Product::byCategory($category->id);
while ($product = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-7"><b>' . $product->name . '</b>'; 
        if($product->is_vegi == YES){echo ' <img src="//dy3erx8o0a6nh.cloudfront.net/images/diet_veg_17px.png" alt="Vegetarian" class="iconVegetarian">';}
    echo "<br />" . $product->description . "</div>";
    echo '<div class="col-md-5">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">&pound;' . $product->price . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" maxlength="2" name="qty" id="qty' . $product->id . '" class="form-control custom-control input-sm" value="1" readonly /></div>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="' . $product->id . '" class="showModalForPizza btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pizzaDetails"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Change</button></div>';
    echo "</div></div></div><br />";
}
```

ID is stored in `id="' . $product->id . '"` full line below

```
echo '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="' . $product->id . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pizzaDetails"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Change</button></div>';
```

The target data is the data stored in the modal with the matching ID. What is the best way to load this data?

Comment: Is AJAX already involved here?

Comment: yes @JuanBonnett it is and thanks for your response... let me try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before a lot of times... what I do is:

1) Have a folder called `ajax` inside my project

2) Inside it I'd put a file called `ajax_get_product_info.php` that will return an HTML response with the product information well structured.

```
//NOTE: CHANGE METHOD NAMES FOR THE EQUIVALENTS ON YOUR FRAMEWORK/CLASS
$productInfo = Product::byId($_GET["id"]); 
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h1><?php echo $productInfo->Title; ?></h1>
         <b>Price: $</b><?php echo $productInfo->Price; ?>
         <hr/>
         <p><?php echo $productInfo->Description; ?></p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <img src="<?php echo $productInfo->ImageURL; ?>" class="dialog-image"/>    
    </div>
</div>
```

3) Use jQuery (that you already have included because you're using Bootstrap) and use one of its AJAX methods to load the returned inside the modal.

You achieve this using the function `$("#modalContent").html(theAjaxResponse)`;

More information about jQuery ajax and examples, here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

When you click on the button, it should trigger the AJAX function to the url `"/ajax/ajax_get_product_info.php?id=" + $(this).id()`

If you read the examples in the jQuery Documentation you might figure it out easily, else, come and ask!

Comment: Thanks @JuanBonnett I've accept you answer that was a great help... :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call Through Javascript

Here is the code

```
$('.showModalForPizza').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'PHPFilename',
        type: 'get',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#pizzaDetails').html(data);
            $('#pizzaDetails').modal('show');
        }
        error: function(){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```